# TextInput.Icon don't show icon recommendations

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper, react-native-textinput, react-native-vector-icons

```
<TextInput
        style={style.container}
        label="Şifre"
        value={text}
        onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
        right={<TextInput.Icon icon="eye"/>}
        underlineStyle={{
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        }}
    />
```

Here when I press ctrl-space I cannot find the recommended icons. How can I know how many icons or the names of the availiable icons are in TextInput.Icon?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a problem with that, you cannot see the icon recommendations, but since TextInput.Icon uses react-native-vector-items you can find your icon in vector-icons. I leave the link to all vector-icons below.

**List of Icons**

[List of all TextInput icons here!](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)